# why my .xprofile file doesn't work?

Tags: xorg, .profile

I have xorg and xinit and I want to start some commands before the X environment. I did this many times and idk bc doesn't work.

I made a `touch ~/.xprofile` and here I wrote the command that I want to run before the X enviroment, the `.xprofile` file has execution permision and has the comment `#!/bin/bash` above of all the commands (I only have 1 command because I am trying) but reading in the arch wiki, this should work.

The permisions of the file:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 28 nov  1 20:04 /root/.xprofile
```

and the file

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap es &
```

Comment: Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xprofile . What is your display manager?

Comment: did you source the xprofile file ? if not this link may help . https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xprofile

Answer (score 1):

You may need add below lines before `exec` in your `.xinitrc` file. Otherwise, the `.xprofile` won't work at all.

```bash
# This line try to import /etc/xprofile if it exists
[ -f /etc/xprofile ] && . /etc/xprofile
# As ditto
[ -f ~/.xprofile ] && . ~/.xprofile
```